# Black and orange spider, what is it?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Found in Alexandria MN, on sidewalk. Small, fast little spider.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like one of the Amaurobiidae - the Hacklemesh weavers, often called Lace Spiders for their fluffy, cottony silk snares/shelters that they spin under rocks and logs.  It's an adult male from the big boxing glove pedipalp structures in front of the face, which is presumably why it was out in the open; it was looking for love.
As to which one it was, I'm not entirely sure - these are not a group I'm too familiar with, and I don't even know what species are found in Minnesota.  It looks a bit like a male Amaurobius ferox (an introduced European species that is spreading across the country from eastern N. America), but even lightening the photo doesn't help reveal the abdominal pattern, I'm afraid.  I'll just go with "probably Amaurobiidae" and suggest you send the photo to Bug Guide for the attantion of the pros over there:  https://bugguide.net/node/view/6/bgimage

Here's a representative male A. ferox for comparison, but note that this is a well-lighted photo so you can see the pattern on the abdomen.  Also note that there is a fair amount of individual variation in these (as in most) spiders, so some are darker, some are lighter, some have obvious patterns, some are more poorly-defined, etc.

[image]